# Python - a type error caused by what?

Tags: python, python-3.x, types, maya

In Python 3, I am trying to connect attributes of an object to equivalent attributes of its proxy object (identified by its "_proxy" suffix).

Here's the code:

```
import maya.cmds as mc

attributes = ['.t', '.r', '.s']

controllers = mc.ls('ctrl_Lip*')

def corresponding_proxy(controller):
    corresponding_proxy = mc.ls(controller+'_proxy')
    return corresponding_proxy

for controller in controllers :
    for attr in attributes :
        mc.connectAttr(controller+attr, corresponding_proxy(controller)+attr)
```

The error returned is :

```
# Error: TypeError: file <maya console> line 13: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list #
```

I don't understand, because I thought `controller`, `corresponding_proxy` and `attr` were all strings.

What did I miss?

Ok jasonharper is right, returning `controller+'_proxy'` makes it work !
However it now throws another error at me :

```
# Error: RuntimeError: file <maya console> line 14: The destination attribute 'ctrl_Lip_Up_1_proxy_proxy.t' cannot be found. #
```

...and it's not doing the operation on the entire list of objects, just the first one and then there's the error.

Ok nevermind ! The ´ls´ command also returned the proxies I had created, so my loop was trying to iterate over the proxies themselves as well...

Thanks a lot everybody ! Solved !
This is the working code :

```
import maya.cmds as mc

attributes = ['.t', '.r', '.s']

controllers = mc.ls('ctrl_Lip*', tr=True)

for controller in controllers:
    mc.duplicate(controller, n=controller+'_proxy')

def corresponding_proxy(controller):
    return controller+'_proxy'

for controller in controllers:
    for attr in attributes:
        mc.connectAttr(controller+attr, corresponding_proxy(controller)+attr)
```

Comment: Is this written in any language in particular, and if so, what is it?

Comment: Oops how do I correct this in my post ? This is Python 3 - Ok got it ! I added a tag and changed the title.

Comment: Is that the only line of the error?  Where is the rest of the traceback?  That should indicate which line of your code is producing the error.

Comment: This is the only line yes. Not sure what traceback is. It does say line 13 though.

Comment: `corresponding_proxy()` is whatever type `mc.ls()` returns, which is apparently a list.  You may just want to return `controller+'_proxy'` there.

Comment: What is the type of your `corresponding_proxy(controller)` and `controller`? THey do not seem to be strings, while your `attr` is a string. You cannot add string with list

Comment: Can you link to the docs of the functions you are using?

Comment: Can you `print(type(controller), controller)`?

Comment: The first result for 'python maya' is https://github.com/kennethreitz/maya/, but it doesnt look like that's the maya that you're using...

Comment: This is the [ls command](http://help.autodesk.com/cloudhelp/2018/CHS/Maya-Tech-Docs/CommandsPython/ls.html). Jasonharper is right returning controller+'_proxy' works !

However it throws another error at me (see updated post).